# Can I drill a bracket for a hanging basket into this column on our deck or will it weaken it?

Tags: hanging, brackets

Our deck has four columns made of wood that support its roof. Can I drill screws into the columns to attach brackets for hanging plant baskets or will this weaken the columns? We hang a swing chair from the roof and I want to make sure that screwing into the columns won’t weaken them too much. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few screws will not hurt.  Even a few hundred screws will not hurt.

Those columns can hold quite a few plant baskets with no problem.

You might want to put in caulking in and around the holes to keep out rain/moisture.